# How to fix year format exception ORA-01841?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this function which takes the last day of month when the days is not conform:

```
create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
begin
  begin
    -- try to convert

    l_date := to_date(p_date ,'yyyymmdd')  ;
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
      -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
      l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));
  end;
  return l_date;
end;
```

It works fine until I have these errors. It seems there are some years that are not correct, how can I fix this issue?

> java.sql.SQLDataException:ORA-01841: L'année (complète) doit être
>   comprise entre -4713 et +9999 et être différente de 0
>
> ORA-06512: à "CRPCEN1.UPDATEDATE", ligne 8

I tried to fix this one by adding this statement but it's not working, as I'm not using 12g:

```
to_date(p_date default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: First you should work out witch which inputs (`p_date`) the error occurs. And it's rather this line `l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));` than that `l_date := to_date(p_date ,'yyyymmdd')  ;` as far as I can tell by `ligne 8`. (Please try to get the English message text of errors also. Even if it's easy to find here because of the `ORA-01841` number.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
begin

  begin
    l_date := to_date(p_date ,'yyyymmdd')  ;
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
         -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
         l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));    
  end;
  return l_date;

exception
   when others then
       Raise_Application_Error(-20001, 'Cannot convert "'||p_date||'"', TRUE);
end;
```

Then you should see bad values in error message.

If you don't like to get any error you can use this one:

```
exception
   when others then
       RETURN NULL;
```

or

```
exception
   when others then
       RETURN SYSDATE;
```

However, this is more like "I close my eyes in order to ignore errors"

Comment: Thank you for your kind help: here is the error msg i got 
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20001: Cannot convert
ORA-06512: à "CRPCEN1.UPDATEDATE", ligne 18
ORA-01841: L'année (complète) doit être comprise entre -4713 et +9999 et être différente de 0

Comment: is there a way to return an empty date when this exception is shown or any date

Comment: is it correct like this create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
 
   l_date1   DATE := SYSDATE;
begin

  begin
    l_date := to_date(p_date ,'yyyymmdd')  ;
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
         -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
         l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));    
  end;
  return l_date;

exception
   when others then
      l_date := l_date1;
      RETURN l_date;
end;

Comment: According error message `ORA-20001: Cannot convert ` it looks like you have an empty sting, e.g. `select to_date(' ' ,'yyyymmdd') from dual`

Comment: yes, it was an empty string, this why i montioned before i return l_date1 DATE := SYSDATE, i, fact i need this field to make sorted resulat by date, and now it works fine